# tengo problemas de compatibilidad con PHPMailer

Tags: php, html5, phpmailer

La cuestión es la siguiente, debido a limitaciones ajenas a mi, debo de reconfigurar el envió de correos de un sistema que esta desarrollado en php 5.2. El problema es que el PHPMailer que es compatible con esa versión de php es la 5.0 y aun con con la configuración adecuada no funciona. pero utilizo la versión de PHPMailer actualizada junto con la versión actual de php todo funciona perfectamente, pero resalto que no puedo simplemente utilizar las versiones nuevas porque no seria compatible con el php usado en el servidor donde se aloja el sistema antes mencionado.

Adjunto el código de ambas versiones:

Versión Funcional:

```html
<?php
require "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
require "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
require "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
 
$oMail= new PHPMailer();
$oMail->isSMTP();
$oMail->Host="mail.servidordelaempresa.com";
$oMail->Port=587;
$oMail->SMTPSecure="tls";
$oMail->SMTPAuth=true;
$oMail->Username="sisad@servidordelaempresa.com";
$oMail->Password="pass1234";
$oMail->setFrom("sisad@servidordelaempresa.com","SISAD");
$oMail->addAddress("rodododo@hotmail.com","Correo de Destino");
$oMail->Subject="MSJ de Prueba";
$oMail->msgHTML("Hola soy un mensaje");
 
if(!$oMail->send())
  echo $oMail->ErrorInfo;
```

Version del sistema, la cual no funciona:

```html
function enviarCorreoEntradaMat($correo, $body, $num_req){
        error_reporting(E_STRICT);
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
        require_once('../../includes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

        $correos = explode(";", $correo);

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host       = "mail.servidordelaempresa.com";
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;

        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->Host       = "mail.servidordelaempresa.com";
        $mail->Port       = 587;
        $mail->Username   = "sisad@servidordelaempresa.com";
        $mail->Password   = "pass1234";

        $mail->SetFrom('sisad@servidordelaempresa.com', 'SISAD');
        $mail->Subject    = "MATERIAL ENTREGADO DE REQUISICION $num_req";

        $mail->Body       = $body;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        foreach ($correos as $email) {
            $email = trim($email);
            $mail->AddAddress($email, "USUARIO SISAD");
        }

        $mail->AddAddress($correo, "USUARIO SISAD");
        $mail->Send();
}

enviarCorreoEntradaMat($correo_requi, $contenido_mensaje, $num_requi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que necesitas que tu sistema funcione tanto en versiones antiguas de PHP como en recientes y sugiero que tengas dos códigos e incluyas el adecuado, de acuerdo a la versión detectada por [phpversion()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.phpversion.php):

```
if(phpversion() <= 5.2) {
    // Incluir librería PHPMailer 5.2, que puedes descargar desde:
    //     https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable
    // Incluir tu script de envío de correos para esta versión
    include 'ruta/correos-anterior.php';
} else {
    // Incluir librería PHPMailer actualizada
    // Incluir tu script de envío de correos para versiones recientes
    include 'ruta/correos-nuevo.php';
}
```

Si los nombres de espacio generan conflicto, entonces dentro de tus scripts incluyes la librería de PHPMailer que corresponda.